# How to create customized error with custom error options in restify 7.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, restify

I would like to create some customized errors in a project, using **restify** (version 7.x) with custom error options. Now I'm able to create a customized error with parameters code and message using [restify-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-errors). And I tried to create an error with more than two params using the [subclassing property](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-errors#subclassing-errors) of **restify-errors** using the `makeConstructor()`.

```
restifyErrors.makeConstructor('ValidationError', {
     restCode: 'ValidationError',
    statusCode: 400,
    message: message
});
var myErr = new errors.ValidationError();
```

But I can't implement it successfully, ended up with the below-shown error

> var myErr = new errors.ValidationError();
>                   ^
>
> TypeError: errors.ValidationError is not a constructor

And also, I tried [restify-error-options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-errors-options) it also wouldn't work for me.
Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem or suggest me how to implement customized errors with custom error options?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem.
The solution is on [their github page](https://github.com/restify/errors#customizing-errors)

```js
function render(req, res, next) {
    var myErr = new errors.InvalidVersionError({
        statusCode: 409
    }, 'Version not supported with current query params');

    res.send(myErr);
    return next();
}
```